# Ordering not working in Entity Framework query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm currently battling a linq query for my application using Entity Framework (6.1.3)

The query is as follows:

```
var productPeriods = (from pp in ctx.ProductPeriods                                          
  where pp.IsActive && pp.Product.IsBuyBackForProduct == null && !pp.Product.ProductAddOns.Any() && pp.PowerRegionID == powerRegionId
  select new
  {
      ProductPeriod = pp,
      Price = pp.Prices
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Created)
        .GroupBy(x => x.FirmID)
        .Select(pr => pr.FirstOrDefault())
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.ProductPrice)
        .FirstOrDefault()
  }).ToList();
```

The purpose of the query is to find the latest price from the prices collection of a product period, grouped by the firm ID and then select the best price of the latest prices from each firm.

This works perfectly in Linqpad, but the first `OrderByDescending(x => x.Created)` doesn't work when used in context of Entity Framework.

Does anyone knows why? And perhaps have a solution for it? :-)

Thanks in advance!

**Update**

Thanks for all replies. I've tried the following:

```
select new {
    ProductPeriod = p,  
    Price = p.Prices.GroupBy(x => x.FirmID).Select(pr => pr.OrderByDescending(x => x.Created).ThenByDescending(x => x.ProductPrice).FirstOrDefault())
}
```

But it seems like `ThenByDescending(x => x.ProductPrice)` gets ignored as well. The prices are not sorted correctly in the output. They're output like this:

```
Price: 0,22940, Created: 06-03-2015 10:15:09,
Price: 0,23150, Created: 06-03-2015 10:05:48
Price: 0,20040, Created: 06-03-2015 09:24:24
```

**Update 2 (solution for now)**

I came to the solution that the initial query just returns the latest prices from each firm. There's currently three firms, so the performance should be alright.

Later in my code, where I'm actually using the latest and best price, I simply do an `.OrderByDescending(x => x.ProductPrice).FirstOrDefault()` and check if it's not null.

I.e:

```
var productPeriods = (from pp in ctx.ProductPeriods
                      where pp.IsActive && pp.Product.IsBuyBackForProduct == null && !pp.Product.ProductAddOns.Any() && pp.PowerRegionID == powerRegionId
                      select new
                      {
                          ProductPeriod = pp,
                          Prices = pp.Prices.GroupBy(x => x.FirmID).Select(pr => pr.OrderByDescending(x => x.Created).FirstOrDefault())
                      }).ToList();
```

Later in my code:

```
var bestPriceOfToday = period.Prices.OrderByDescending(x => x.ProductPrice).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: Is there any exception?

Comment: ordering and then grouping won't preserve the order, especially if you're re-ordering. look into `ThenByDescending()` to do a second ordering

Comment: No exception being thrown, but the results are not correct :-) I'll definitely look into the ThenByDescending call. Thanks a lot!

On a side note, I just read that this is a bug in the entity framework, can anyone confirm this?

Comment: what are the data types?  Is Created a datetime?

Comment: Yes, "Created" is a DateTime and "ProductPrice" is a decimal :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the commands you are using. OrderBy  and OrderByDescending do NOT add additional order by statements to the resulting query but instead they CREATE the order by statement and eliminate all orderby statements that existed before.

In order to use multiple orderby's you need to do the following:

- OrderBy   or OrderByDescending
- ThenBy    or ThenByDescending

the ThenBy statements can be used 1 or more times they just add additional order statements to the resulting query.

Comment: And you would need to move the Created orderby to be just above the ProductPrice one (with thenby). An order by before a group is not clear - in SQL you put orderbys after groupings. It might still work but it's not obvious that you need to use thenby, unless they're juxtaposed.

Comment: the group by COULD be used before an orderby (didnt try so far) in linq BECAUSE the statement itself is only run when it is needed, thus in this case when the ToList() is being made. until then the query is not executed thus it should not be a problem (but like I said didn't try it out if the order of groupby/orderby is important before the ToList or not)

Answer (score 0):

According to yours update, omnit `select` and type:

```
select new {
    ProductPeriod = p,  
    Price = p.Prices.GroupBy(x => x.FirmID)
        .OrderByDescending(x =>x.Created).ThenByDescending(x=>x.ProductPrice).FirstOrDefault()
}
```

That `select` was useless and could be the cause of problem

Comment: Hi @michasm, thanks for the input :-) I don't think the select was useless since I start by grouping the prices by the firm ID. If I skip the select, I can't order by Created since the collection is now a grouping and not a collection of price. Makes sense? :-)

Comment: mmm, right @BoMortensen it's in group, now it's seems legit to me :)