# Ordering missing in entity framework query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have the following C# code generating a query on a sqlserver.

```
return c.Bags
        .Where(b => b.RollformerId == RollformerId
           && (!b.Order.OnHold.HasValue || b.Order.OnHold.Value == false)
           && (!b.Order.Archive.HasValue || b.Order.Archive.Value == false)
           && (!b.Order.Inactive.HasValue || b.Order.Inactive.Value == false)
           && (b.BagStatus.BagStatusId == notStarted
                          || b.BagStatus.BagStatusId == inProgress))
        .OrderBy(b => b.Priority)
        .ThenBy(b => b.ScheduleDate)
        .SelectMany(b => b.Packs
                     .OrderBy(p => p.PackSequence))
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

It generates the following sql code:

```
SELECT 
[Limit1].[BatchID] AS [BatchID], 
[Limit1].[RollformerID] AS [RollformerID], 
[Limit1].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Limit1].[OrderID] AS [OrderID], 
[Limit1].[BagId] AS [BagId], 
[Limit1].[PackSequence] AS [PackSequence], 
[Limit1].[PackStatusId] AS [PackStatusId], 
[Limit1].[Priority] AS [Priority], 
[Limit1].[ProductID] AS [ProductID], 
[Limit1].[DeliveryID] AS [DeliveryID]
FROM ( SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Extent4].[BatchID] AS [BatchID], 
    [Extent4].[DeliveryID] AS [DeliveryID], 
    [Extent4].[Priority] AS [Priority], 
    [Extent4].[ProductID] AS [ProductID], 
    [Extent4].[RollformerID] AS [RollformerID], 
    [Extent4].[Description] AS [Description], 
    [Extent4].[OrderID] AS [OrderID], 
    [Extent4].[BagId] AS [BagId], 
    [Extent4].[PackSequence] AS [PackSequence], 
    [Extent4].[PackStatusId] AS [PackStatusId]
    FROM    [dbo].[Bag] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Orders] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[OrderId] = [Extent2].[OrderID]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Orders] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[OrderId] = [Extent3].[OrderID]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Batches] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent1].[BagId] = [Extent4].[BagId]
    WHERE ([Extent2].[OnHold] IS NULL OR [Extent3].[OnHold] = 0) 
    AND ([Extent3].[Archive] = 0 OR [Extent3].[Archive] IS NULL) 
    AND ([Extent3].[Inactive] = 0 OR [Extent3].[Inactive] IS NULL) 
    AND ([Extent1].[RollformerId] = @p__linq__0) 
    AND ([Extent1].[BagStatusId] IN (@p__linq__1,@p__linq__2))
)  AS [Limit1]
```

Comparing the output to the original, it appears that the **ordering statements** have been c**ompletely ignored** in the generated SQL.

Could someone please identify what is wrong with my statement to have the ordering ignored.

The solutions provided in [Ordering not working in Entity Framework query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29944861/ordering-not-working-in-entity-framework-query) did not suit this situation (at least to my satisfaction)

UPDATE:

The first set of orderby is on the main entity, where I wish to select the first one within the order, and the subsequent selectmany is on the detail records, or which I wish to get the first.

On thinking about it, the selectmany is not required in this instance as I only want the packs from the first of the result.

Comment: I am reluctant to post this as an answer because I don't know if it's the case but it might help you think about the problem.  I think it's to do with the fact that none of your order by parts really affect the outcome.  It's like having ORDER BY in a view - pointless because you want to ORDER BY the final outcome.  So I think you need to have your .OrderBy after your SelectMany and FirstOrDefault on that rather than buried inside.

Comment: @LoztInSpace Conceptually I can see that making sense somewhat - but an `OrderBy()` after `FirstOrDefault()` doesn't make too much sense - this is an odd one for sure.

Comment: Sorry - not what I am saying. 

 Do .Where.SelectMany.OrderBy.FirstOrDefault.

Comment: You're spot-on - `SelectMany` doesn't return an `IOrderedEnumerable` like `OrderBy` does, so it would need to be after the `SelectMany` call.

Comment: I am most likely missing a FirstOrDefault before the selectmany which is to give me the result I would like, which is probably what is misleading everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your update, I think you're aiming for something like this:

```
return c.Bags
        .Where(b => b.RollformerId == RollformerId
           && (!b.Order.OnHold.HasValue || b.Order.OnHold.Value == false)
           && (!b.Order.Archive.HasValue || b.Order.Archive.Value == false)
           && (!b.Order.Inactive.HasValue || b.Order.Inactive.Value == false)
           && (b.BagStatus.BagStatusId == notStarted
                          || b.BagStatus.BagStatusId == inProgress))
        .OrderBy(b => b.Priority)
        .ThenBy(b => b.ScheduleDate)
        .FirstOrDefault().Packs
        .Select(b => b.Packs)
        .OrderBy(p => p.PackSequence);
```

This would select and order `Bag` entities as per your original query, take the top one, then select and order the `bag.Packs` collection on the selected `Bag`.

---

Original Answer below.

@LoztInSpace has the right idea here.

Ultimately, when you use `SelectMany()` and flatten the results like you do, you'll want to `OrderBy(),`ThenBy()`ect after the`SelectOrMany()` call.

Consider the output of this query:

```
var qry = ctx.Users
    .Where(u => u.EmailAddress != String.Empty)
    .SelectMany(u => u.Surveys)
    .OrderBy(s => s.Time)
    .ThenBy(s => s.Respondent_Uid);

SELECT [Project1].[Id] AS [Id]
    ,[Project1].[Time] AS [Time]
    ,[Project1].[Type] AS [Type]
    ,[Project1].[Respondent_Uid] AS [Respondent_Uid]
    ,[Project1].[SubjectOfSurvey_Uid] AS [SubjectOfSurvey_Uid]
FROM (
    SELECT [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id]
        ,[Extent2].[Time] AS [Time]
        ,[Extent2].[Type] AS [Type]
        ,[Extent2].[Respondent_Uid] AS [Respondent_Uid]
        ,[Extent2].[SubjectOfSurvey_Uid] AS [SubjectOfSurvey_Uid]
    FROM [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Surveys] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Uid] = [Extent2].[Respondent_Uid]
    WHERE NOT (
            ([Extent1].[EmailAddress] = @p__linq__0)
            AND (
                0 = (
                    CASE 
                        WHEN (@p__linq__0 IS NULL)
                            THEN cast(1 AS BIT)
                        ELSE cast(0 AS BIT)
                        END
                    )
                )
            )
    ) AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[Time] ASC
    ,[Project1].[Respondent_Uid] ASC
```

The order by is where we want there. Contrast to this query:

```
var qry = ctx.Users
    .Where(u => u.EmailAddress != String.Empty)
    .OrderBy(u => u.FirstName)
    .SelectMany(u => u.Surveys.OrderBy(s => s.Time));

SELECT [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id]
    ,[Extent2].[Time] AS [Time]
    ,[Extent2].[Type] AS [Type]
    ,[Extent2].[Respondent_Uid] AS [Respondent_Uid]
    ,[Extent2].[SubjectOfSurvey_Uid] AS [SubjectOfSurvey_Uid]
FROM [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Surveys] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Uid] = [Extent2].[Respondent_Uid]
WHERE NOT (
        ([Extent1].[EmailAddress] = @p__linq__0)
        AND (
            0 = (
                CASE 
                    WHEN (@p__linq__0 IS NULL)
                        THEN cast(1 AS BIT)
                    ELSE cast(0 AS BIT)
                    END
                )
            )
        )
```

Note no order at all, because it ultimately doesn't matter.

Comment: Nice example.  Shame I was too lazy to write one up :)  It's a fairly common problem with SQL - a view or sub query has an ORDER BY but not the actual SELECT

Comment: Having the orderby after the selectmany changes the result of the query.  the selectmany is on detail records whereas the initial ordering is on the master records.

Comment: @sweetfa I updated based upon what I believe to be your intent.